# How to make a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, return

Assume,

```
range(len(column)) = 4
column = ['AAA', 'CTC', 'GTC', 'TTC']
for i in range(len(column)):
    a = list(column[i])
```

Outside of this loop I want a variable,say x to be assigned such that it gives the following output.

```
 ['A', 'A', 'A']
 ['C', 'T', 'C']
 ['G', 'T', 'C']
 ['T', 'T', 'C']
```

---

After doing this, here is what I should be able to do:
In the Next, I want to compare within x. Say x[2] to tell me if 'G' is different from 'T' and if 'G' is different from 'C' and if 'T' is different from 'C'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are in need of a list of lists

Code:

```
column = ['AAA', 'CTC', 'GTC', 'TTC']
x=[]
for i in range(len(column)):
    a = list(column[i])
    x.append(a)

print x
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['C', 'T', 'C'], ['G', 'T', 'C'], ['T', 'T', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what kind of comparison you want to do once you've formatted your data, but this is something

```
import numpy as np

alt_col = [list(y) for y in column]
x = np.asarray(alt_col)
```

you can then compare whatever you want within the array

```
print all(x[1, :] == x[2, :])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create `x` without using `numpy` or other external module:

```
column = ['AAA', 'CTC', 'GTC', 'TTC']
x = [list(column[i]) for i in range(len(column))]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['C', 'T', 'C'], ['G', 'T', 'C'], ['T', 'T', 'C']]
```

To use this you'll need to two indices: Which you can think of as the first representing the row and the second the column. For example the `'G'` is in `x[2][0]`. You can compare it to any other cell in `x` using the same notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputs = ['ABC','DEF','GHI'] # list of inputs
outputs = [] # creates an empty list to be populated
for i in range(len(inputs)): # steps through each item in the list
    outputs.append([]) # adds a list into the output list, this is done for each item in the input list
    for j in range(len(inputs[i])): # steps through each character in the strings in the input list
        outputs[i].append(inputs[i][j]) # adds the character to the [i] position in the output list

outputs
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]
```

edit
added comments as to what each line is doing

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.